# How to define a shortcut with more than one key (other than mod, ctrl and shift)

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, awesome

Within `awful.key` you can define a keyboard shortcut with modkey + shift or control and a key. Is there a way to define a shortcut involving more than one key. For instance I would like to define the shortcut ***modkey + right arrow + up arrow*** to move a window to the top right in a free tiled tag.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
awful.key({ modkey, "Right", }, "Up", function () ...
```